# Euler theorem's inverse proposition in number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

The Euler theorem

$\mathbf (a,n)=1 \Rightarrow a ^\phi$ = $ 1(mod n)$   ($ \phi $ means $ \phi(n)$)

Inverse of the above proposition that

**$\mathbf a ^\phi $ = 1(mod n)  $\Rightarrow $ (a,n)=1**

I'm tried to find the counterexamples of the inverse of Euler theorem is not true.

But Every example what I've take like unit group $U_n = \{\ n \vert \ (a,n)=1 \}\ $ where n=5,7,...
I failed.

please give me some hints.

Plus If the inverse of Euler proposition is true, How Could I prove that?

Comment: Take the contrapositive of the statement $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n \implies (a,n) = 1$. What happens when $(a,n) > 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n \\ $,

by definition of modular arithmetic, there exists $ k \in \mathbb Z $ such that 
$a^{\phi(n)}= 1+ n k \\$,

hence if $c$ is any positive common divisor of $a^\phi(n)$ and $n$,

then $c$ divides $a^{\phi(n)}- n k$, which is $1$,

hence $c=1$,

hence $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Perfect proof! Thank you